# В каком формате передается не-ASCII текст по HTTP1.1?

Tags: http, сеть, utf-8, binary, ascii

В каком формате передается не-US-ASCII текст (например, русские символы UTF-8) по HTTP1.1? Ведь HTTP1.1 умеет передавать только US-ASCII-текст, а UTF-8, который не US-ASCII уже по сути бинарник?

Тот же вопрос для передачи изображения, в каком формате передается изображение по HTTP1.1?

Comment: @Arhad а это в каком-нибудь стандарте написано, что обязательно должно передаваться в base64? Или можно и в другом формате?

Comment: Вы про содержимое или про заголовки?

Comment: @AlexeyTen да про все

Comment: Содержимое отлично передаётся в бинарном виде.

Comment: А с заголовками беда — стандарта нет. Сейчас вроде более-менее все сходятся на urlencoded utf-8, но возможны варианты. В общем в заголовках лучше избегать не-ascii

Comment: @AlexeyTen тогда я что-то не пойму, почему тогда HTTP1.1 считается текстовым а не бинарным? И многие утверждают, что он не понимает бинарный формат?

Comment: Кем считается? Может Япотому что служебная информация идёт человекочитаемым текстом, в отличии от какой-нибудь Corba

Comment: @Alexey Ten Так служебная она всегда в ASCII, это очевидно, там везде английский текст и цифры. Т.е. правильно ли я понимаю, что картинки и прочие данные передаются по HTTP1.1 в бинарном виде без всякого конвертирования в base-64 (конечно можно извратиться и сконвертировать, но такого требования нет и все спокойно передается)?

Comment: @Arhad по вашей ссылке вообще говорится, что это требование для электронной почты про перевод в base-64, а не HTTP

Comment: @Arhad Так все же, почему HTTP1.1 текстовый протокол, а HTTP2 бинарный? Если конвертировать, как выяснилось, необязательно, HTTP1.1 прекрасно передает все в бинарном виде?

Comment: @Arhad или не выяснилось и вы сами точно не знаете передает ли бинарные данные HTTP1.1?